Minio - (err: any, dataStream: any) => any' has no properties in common with type 'VersionIdentificator'. Did you mean to call it?
hello Everyone i need help this i had error on function using minio
(err: any, dataStream: any) => any' has no properties in common with type 'VersionIdentificator'. Did you mean to call it?
but few days ago this had no error on today that gives error on the code but when running there's no problem i can access the image but blocking when deploying
i have no clue what i'm changing i'm not touching it almost 2 month
here's my full function for StorageView i'm following minio documentation
export async function StorageView(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<any> {
  try {
    const objectName: any = req.query?.objectName ?? null;
    if (!objectName) return await NotFound(res, 'file not found!');

    minioClient.getObject(
      MINIO_DEFAULT_BUCKET,
      objectName,
      (err, dataStream) => { //**Here's The Error**
        if (err) {
          if (err.message.includes('does not exist')) {
            return NotFound(res, 'file not found!');
          } else {
            return ServerError(req, res, 'Error retrieving the file!', err);
          }
        }

        if (!dataStream) {
          return ServerError(
            req,
            res,
            'Error retrieving the file!',
            new Error('No data stream')
          );
        }

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
        return dataStream.pipe(res);
      }
    );
  } catch (error: any) {
    return await ServerError(req, res, 'something went wrong!', error);
  }
}

